# MYSQL moving data after distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data I am pulling from one table to another table but I have a Primary key on the ID column. how do I pull the rest of the data after a Select distinct to make sure I don't have duplicates in the primary?

```
INSERT INTO `goac`.`store`(`STORE_ID`)
select distinct STORE_ID
from ods_sale_large
```

[image: for example I have this]

where I have gotten the distinct store_id from it and inserted into the table but I need the rest of the data to come with.

Comment: Why do you copy data between tables?

Comment: I am pulling from a larger table that has many different values but I only need the ones that pertain to the store. I only need the distinct values from that as well.

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/ you can use row_number to get a single record per store_id.  If the rest of the data is all dupes, just keep using distinct.

Comment: Consider creating a view instead of copying data around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is in case of duplicate keys between existing records in the target table and the source query. You can use then `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`  . **As an example,** If your table `goac`.`store` has a primary key on `STORE_ID` and a field `DUPLICATE_STORE_ID`, you can insert only the missing keys from `ods_sale_large` as new records and store the duplicate keys between `ods_sale_large` and `goac`.`store` in the field `DUPLICATE_STORE_ID` of the existing records :

```sql
INSERT INTO `goac`.`store` (`STORE_ID`)
select distinct STORE_ID from ods_sale_large
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `DUPLICATE_STORE_ID` = VALUES(`STORE_ID`);
```

Comment: thanks this works!  now i need to learn how to do a join